# Add excel file to Julia MacOS

Tags: julia

I'm using Julia on Macbook and am having trouble importing an excel file to it.
This is what I've used but it won't work.

using XLSX

#set datafile's location

cd("/Users/myname/Desktop/cpsmar.xlsx")

xf = XLSX.readxlsx("cpsmar.xlsx")

How can I fix this?

Comment: "it won't work" - any messages, errors, sounds, or other useful diagnostic information?

Comment: I already found the problem. I should have just put cd("/Users/myname/Desktop")